# Jetpack Compose Animation Laggy - Need Help Identifying the Issue

Tags: android, kotlin, animation, android-jetpack-compose, android-animation

I'm relatively new to Jetpack Compose and currently working on an onboarding screen with animated transitions. I'm facing issues with laggy animations and seeking guidance to identify the problem.

I'm working on an onboarding screen in Jetpack Compose and experiencing laggy animations. I'm using the AnimatedContent to transitions between onboarding pages. However, the animations seem to be lagging, and I'm struggling to pinpoint the issue.

```
val TransitionSpec: Any.() -> ContentTransform = {
    fadeIn(
        animationSpec = tween(
            durationMillis = 500,
            easing = FastOutLinearInEasing
        )
    ) + slideInHorizontally { it } togetherWith fadeOut(
        animationSpec = tween(
            durationMillis = 500,
            easing = FastOutLinearInEasing
        )
    ) + slideOutHorizontally { -it }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalAnimationApi::class)
@Composable
fun OnBoardingScreen(onBoardPage: Int, onBoardPageChange: (old: Int) -> Unit = {}) {
    // ... (onBoardList and other components)

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier,
    ) {
        TopLottieSec(onBoardPage = onBoardPage, onBoardList = onBoardList)
        BottomLottieSection(
            title = onBoardList[onBoardPage].title,
            description = onBoardList[onBoardPage].description,
            onBoardPage = onBoardPage
        ) {
            onBoardPageChange(onBoardPage)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun TopLottieSec(
    onBoardPage: Int,
    onBoardList: List<Onboard>,
) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier,
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxHeight(0.35f),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
        ) {
            AnimatedContent(targetState = onBoardPage, transitionSpec = TransitionSpec ) {
                lootie(pageIndex = it)
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun lootie(pageIndex: Int, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    // ... (lottieSpecList and other components)
    
    val lottiespec by remember(pageIndex) { mutableStateOf(lottieSpecList[pageIndex]) }
    val lottieComposition by rememberLottieComposition(lottiespec)

    LottieAnimation(
        composition = lottieComposition,
        modifier = modifier,
        iterations = LottieConstants.IterateForever
    )
}
```

**Issue:**
The animations within the AnimatedContent are not as smooth as expected, and there's noticeable lag. I suspect the issue might be related to the custom TransitionSpec, but I'm not sure where to start debugging. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

**TheActivity Code**

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            VoxTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    var boardPage by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
                    var goToLogin by remember(boardPage) { mutableStateOf(boardPage > 5) }
                    AnimatedContent(targetState = goToLogin) { Login ->
                        when (Login) {
                            true -> LoginScreen()
                            false -> OnBoardingScreen(
                                onBoardPage = boardPage,
                                onBoardPageChange = { boardPage = it + 1 },
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also have tried the Following :

TransitionSpec Adjustment: I've experimented with different TransitionSpec configurations to improve animation smoothness, but the lag persists.

Real Device Testing: To rule out emulator-related issues, I've built and tested the APK on a real device, but the animation performance remains unsatisfactory.

Lottie Composition List: I've even created a list of Lottie compositions (lottieSpecList) to preload them and potentially reduce lag, but unfortunately, this hasn't resolved the issue.

Comment: use the [layout inspector](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tooling/layout-inspector#recomposition-counts) and check how many times each element recomposes